# AJAX - send to another php file while staying on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a question,referring to a question I asked : [Fullcalendar - save events in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522927/fullcalendar-save-events-in-database)

In the end of this question, I asked, whether I can do this with AJAX, and I think I can. But I'm not sure, wether my ideas can work.

Can I do something like a Ajax-Call, with the data I enter with javascript into calendar, having a url to another php file (for example `process_calendar_data.php`), which will then enter the data to the database? If this works in general, the question is, can I in the meantime stay on the same page, and just have the php-file running in background, or do I have to send it to the php file, than let the php-file run and having a `header()` at the end of it?

Comment: ajax run on the background so you dont need to go to another page

Comment: so I can send data, to a php-file, which runs in background then, while I can do other things on the page, I have the call?

Comment: It's a good thing **AJAX/XHR *doesn't* cause a redirect** (or even a DOM reload)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX running in background, just call the `php` file through the `URL` and post the data and insert data in database through`the php` file.

After insert is success, respond with a success message, along with the inserted data.

If required, pull the data respect to the calendar dates, if any error just return the failure message and show with the help of `javascript`.